# What is this package looking icon mean in this UML diagram?

Tags: java, constructor, uml

I got this diagram from netbeans and I have no idea what does the package looking icon and the "~" at the Tetrahedron(int a) means

[image]

Comment: Which UML tool is used here? It might be that the tool adds "tool specific" information. ( I *think* this isn't the Netbeans standard UML, did you install some specific plugin ). Beyond that; I would be guessing that this is a package protected constructor taking an int argument. In any case, your first stop should be the documentation/help for the UML tool you are using.

Comment: Just a question about your question is the constructor declared with a specific keyword ? Because you get some public methods, some protected methods and a constructor with a visibility of type package. Do you use a specific keyword for it ?

Comment: since its package private, I didn't use any keyword when creating the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Those are visibility indicators. P. 118 (and others) in the UML 2.5 specs:

> `<visibility> is the visibility of the Operation (see 7.4).
>   <visibility> ::= ‘+’ | ‘-‘ | ‘#’ | ‘~’`

P. 246:

> The visibility of a packagedElement may be indicated by preceding the name by a visibility symbol (‘+’ for public and ‘-’ for private). Packages may not have protected or package visibility.

and on P 167:

[image]

Interestingly there is no place where all symbols are related to their meaning. So you just "guess" it from the order in the diagram that `protected` is `#` and package is `~`.

The graphical adornments are inventions of the tool creator, so not UML standard. The box icon likely is used for operations and balls for attributes (plus some extra gimmick I can't guess; looks like a key for probably a constant attribute?). The icon top near the name might be derived from a stereotype, but I guess it's just something you find in the tool manual. Not necessarily wrong from a UML perspective, but, as you encountered, simply confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol left to the tilde symbol (`~`) is not part of UML as a language. It is added by the software you're using for creating/viewing the diagram.

The tilde symbol itself represents `package private` visibility in UML, which is what, I guess, is the icon trying to visualize.

When a constructor is **package private** it's only accessible by classes within the same package.

Similarly, the red circle next to the "`+`" symbol for the `public visibility` and the red circle with a key next to "`#`" symbol (for `protected visibility`) seem to visually represent the visibility of the members.

Comment: the hash symbol mean protected, I know its hardly used but I have to use it for my class homework.

Comment: That's correct. "-" means private. Corrected the answer. Thank you for notice.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I down voted since I mis-read the first sentence. I'll make a dummy edit to take it back.

Answer (score 1):

The ~ denotes package level access for the constructor, sorry, not sure what the icons mean.